# Integrated Tomcat in Maven reload sources?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I am using maven for my webapplication to build, start and handle the libraries. So I run tomcat7:run to develop my application... But if I change the code the tomcat will not automatic reload the code changes, so I need to restart. Before maven I use the "Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin" to run and create my project. This plugin allows to the see code changes instant and I know that the PLAY! Framework do the same. So it is possible to configure maven to reload my code changes on running? I will improve my work progress...

Answer (score 10):

It is possible to automatically reload code changes by making sure the Tomcat [context is reloadable](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes). 
The `tomcat7:run` goal allows you to enable context reloading with the `contextReloadable` [parameter](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-mojo.html#contextReloadable) which must be configured in the `configuration` section of the plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: That is for reloading the hole application, but justs a few changes in the code? Change logger.debug("Test"); to logger.debug("Test2");?
A application reload not what i am looking for, only if I change a method signature...

Comment: The Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin does the same thing behind the scenes. I'm afraid this is how far it goes without using advanced tools such as JRebel or DCEVM. Read what the Tomcat documentation says about reloadable contexts: "Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically reload the web application if a change is detected"

Comment: Yes, the reload of the webapplication... But the plugin reloads only the class... I just can develop a webservice and press reload site and get the changes without reload the hole webapplication. That's the magic and I would like to know if this it is possible with maven.

Comment: Ok I get it. I was wrong about the Sysdeo Plugin - it has a dedicated classloader. I'm not aware that this is possible with the Maven plugin, sorry.

Comment: I think only JRebel is what I am looking for... But I need to pay 300 Dollar per year and that is much as private developer.

Comment: As I understand, JRebel is free for non-commercial use: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/jrebel-social-tutorial/. You could also have a look at http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/, although it seems very much experimental.